# vis.js : Offset Node Label

Tags: vis.js, vis.js-network

Vis.js, Network module.

How can I adjust the vertical offset of a label relative to the node's image (or whatever other shape)?

Right now it (the label) sits a little too far below each node for my liking - in fact, I would like to have the label overlay the node.

Answer (score -1):

you can create a variable for e.g.

```
var label1 = {
    content: "Label 1 (with offset)",
    xOffset: 20,
    yOffset: 20
};
```